# regular expression / preg_match_all with optional matching

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a very minimal templating system for my sites users, allowing them to add in variables to their content.

What I'd like is a regular expression to run on the following in php:

```
<p>Hi {{ user.name | fallback="awesome person" }}!</p>
```

Which will give me back the following items at a minimum:

1. {{ user.name | fallback="awesome person" }}
2. user.name
3. awesome person

This needs to also match on the following:

`<p>Your site is {{ site.name }}</p>`

Which would give me back:

1. {{ site.name }}
2. site.name

I'd add in all the things I've tried, however each new try I've basically overwritten the last attempt, regex isn't my strong point!

Ideally, I'll run the regex on the whole content, and it will give me back an array of all the matches, so I can then loop through and replace (1) with `$data[(2)]`, unless (2) doesn't exist in which case I'll add in the (3) fallback.

e.g., if the user.name is present in my array, the response would be

```
Hi Frank!
```

if not, the response would be

```
Hi awesome person!
```

I can take care of the looping / substiting etc, it's the original regular expression that I need the help on, any ideas?

Ideally also, the spaces would be optional, i.e., `{{user.name|fallback="awesome person"}}` would also work

Comment: Add in the last thing you've tried. I don't see any regex attempt :)

Comment: @Jack the furthest I got reliably was as raw as `/{{(.*)}}/` which was enough to get me the result when I wasn't introducing the fallback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nifty way is to use `preg_replace_callback()`:

```php
$txt = 'Hello {{ user.name | fallback="awesome person" }}';

$context = array(
        'user.name' => 'Jack',
);

$re = '/{{\s*([a-z.]+)(?:\s*\|\s*fallback="([^"]+)")?\s*}}/';

echo preg_replace_callback($re, function($match) use ($context) {
        if (isset($context[$match[1]])) {
                return $context[$match[1]];
        } elseif (isset($match[2])) {
                return $match[2];
        } else {
                return '';
        }
}, $txt);
```

Each time a part of the text matches your expression it will call an anonymous function that will return the result based on the given `$context`.

A small explanation on the expression:

```
/{{\s*([a-z.]+)(?:\s*\|\s*fallback="([^"]+)")?\s*}}/
       ^--+--^ ^------------+-------|--+--|--^
          |                 |          |
          |                 |     (fallback value)
          |                 |
      (variable name) (optional fallback segment)
```

Comment: oh man, that's unreal. First of all, the regex is bang on the money, exactly what I was after. Second, the callback functionality, awesome.
All the points to you!

Comment: @duellsy You're welcome! Btw, you could simplify the fallback to just `{{ user.name | "Default value" }}`. Looks cleaner.

Comment: dammit I was working on this and came up with almost exactly what you did, except I did some exploding and trimming instead of a stricter regex. Need to work on my typing speed. +1

Comment: @Jack the shorter version looks nicer for sure, I think though that with the "fallback=" section makes it more obvious to users on how to add in their fallback

Comment: @duellsy It's also more typing and more to remember :)

Comment: @Jack true, I'm going to attempt to build something where they would just click on an item in the editor which would insert that block into their content, but still, I get your point, very valid.